# disable Reactive Mongo plugin in Play 2.3.x

Tags: reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

Is there a way to disable the Reactive Mongo plugin on the command line in Play 2.3.x? Something like `play.evolutions.enabled=false`.

My use case is that I have certain servers that talk to Mongo only & some that talk to another DB only. I want the Mongo servers to be the only ones that connect to Mongo. I don't want to split the code base since it's logically one product.

I'm using
`"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.1.play23"`

Comment: Why not just having a different `play.plugins` without the plugin, for the deployment without

Comment: yes, that is one solution. I thought there would be a cleaner solution from the command line with less devops work